# Adding text to an image with Elixir Mogrify

Tags: imagemagick, elixir, mogrify

I'm having trouble with the [Mogrify](https://github.com/route/mogrify/blob/master/lib/mogrify.ex) package in Elixir. I have an image that I want to add text to. For some reason the image will open and save a copy without any issues but I can't get the copy to be changed in any way.

```
    img_url = to_string(:code.priv_dir(:jobs)) <> "/tristar.png"
    save_url = to_string(:code.priv_dir(:jobs)) <> "/tristar_copy.png"

    Mogrify.open(img_url)
    |> Mogrify.custom("pointsize", 200)
    |> Mogrify.custom("gravity", "North")
    |> Mogrify.custom("annotate", "+0,+100 'Testing'")
    |> IO.inspect(label: "\n===== Image Pre-Save =============================================")
    |> Mogrify.save(path: save_url)
```

The output in Iex looks like:

```
===== Image Pre-Save =============================================:
%Mogrify.Image{
  animated: false,
  buffer: nil,
  dirty: %{},
  ext: ".png",
  format: nil,
  frame_count: 1,
  height: nil,
  operations: [
    {"pointsize", 200},
    {"gravity", "North"},
    {"annotate", "+0,+100 'Testing'"}
  ],
  path: "/code/elixir/_build/dev/lib/jobs/priv/tristar.png",
  width: nil
}
%Mogrify.Image{
  animated: false,
  buffer: nil,
  dirty: %{},
  ext: ".png",
  format: nil,
  frame_count: 1,
  height: nil,
  operations: [],
  path: "/code/elixir/_build/dev/lib/jobs/priv/tristar_copy.png",
  width: nil
}
```

I've tried adding fill and stroke with `custom`. I've tried using `label`, `draw text`, and `annotate`. The saved image at the end is simply a copy of the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are one comma away from a working solution:

Change `"+0,+100 'Testing'"` to `"+0+100 'Testing'"`.

Answer (score 0):

After spending alot of hours troubleshooting this i found the problem i had atleast, i had no fonts installed for imagemagick,

I fixed it by replacing `<include file="type-ghostscript.xml" />` in this file:  `usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-7/etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml`
with  `<include file="type-apple.xml" />`

Then edit `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-7/etc/ImageMagick-7/type-apple.xml`
In this file search and replace all glyphs path with `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental`